# angularjs ng-class not work in table ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

    $scope.tableData = ['hello','blue','angular'];

    //set ture ok but only first time
    //设置 true 可以 但是 只有第一次可以
    //$scope.selectClass = true;


    $scope.reset = function(){
        console.log('reset');
        $scope.selectClass = false;
    }

}]).directive('myTd',function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope,elem){
            $(elem).on('click',function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
                    $(this).removeClass('selected')
                }else{
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.selected {background: #139029;}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    .selected {background: #139029;}
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>item1</th>
                    <th>item2</th>
                    <th>item3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in [1,2,3]">
                    <td ng-class="{'selected':selectClass}" ng-repeat="item in tableData" my-td >{{item}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ng-click="reset();">重置表格</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="lib/angular.1.5.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/resetTable.js"></script>
</html>
```

i click button reset class not work, why? who can tell me. thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that directive (and you don't need to manipulate the DOM yorself). ng-class is itself a built-in directive that does just that.

Just delete your myTd directive and change your element to this:

```html
<td ng-class="{'selected':selectClass}" ng-repeat="item in tableData" ng-click="selectClass = !selectClass" >{{item}}</td>
```

Comment: You may not understand what I mean, I would like to click the button under the table, the table will have style ( "selected") td all removed

Comment: Added: I have chosen td this operation, marking some td is selected, which has not been selected, this is a necessary condition

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you want to do to achieve your requirement by preserving the directive is to remove the class `selected` from your table rows

To do that modify the reset function as follows

```
$scope.reset = function(){      
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
}
```

This function selects all the elements with class name `selected` and will remove the class from those elements

Comment: "Controller" generally do not allow operation dom, so I do not think this is the ideal way

Comment: Actually in your case your directive 'myTd' is doing a DOM manipulation. So you have to undo the DOM manipulation to reset the grid. We can perform DOM manipulations using Controller